# Simple DOM and Sony.co.za?

Tags: php, simpledom

I have been running my simple dom script on a variety of pages for weeks, and never have I come across any issues. Now, today, when I try:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.sony.co.za/product/dsc-wx10');
```

I get:

```
( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.sony.co.za/product/dsc-wx10) 
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
 in C:\XXXXXXX\simplephpdom\simple_html_dom.php on line 70
```

What could possibly cause me to not be able to enter the code above with success, when the following works:

```
 $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com');
 $html = file_get_html('http://www.whatever.com');
```

I am able to access the Sony page via my browser. And as far as I understand, the code above connects to port 80, just like I do. So I find it hard to believe I'm being blocked. And also, I was blocked from Day 1.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site seems to delay requests containing the PHP user agent forever. Sounds like a really, **really** lame attempt to stop crawlers.

The solution is simple: Use curl to send the request and specify a "normal" useragent.

---

Update: Apparently it also blocks empty/missing user agents:

```
> nc www.sony.co.za 80
nc: using stream socket
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.sony.co.za
User-Agent: Mozilla Firefox

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
...
```

vs

```
> nc www.sony.co.za 80
nc: using stream socket
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.sony.co.za
[no response]
```

Comment: Thank you. Will test now and report back. but do you mind telling me how you figured that out?

Comment: It was a guess since `file_get_contents()` failed but `curl` worked so I decided to test it using netcat.

Comment: mine's not workin with curl either. Do you mind sharing the code you useD?

Comment: @RD: I added some PHP example code how to set the user-agent, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10188476/367456.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using `simple_html_dom` ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ) ... instead of using `file_get_html` you can use `str_get_html` with `curl`

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url="http://www.sony.co.za/product/dsc-wx10";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9");
$exec = curl_exec ($ch);
$html = str_get_html($exec);
var_dump($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the user-agent (header), then it works:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla Firefox'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$url = 'http://www.sony.co.za/product/dsc-wx10';
$str = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
$html = str_get_html($str);
```

Simple HTML DOM requires here that you do the work for it (loading the string from the remote server), I'd generally say you should take `DOMDocument` instead of that "simple" HTML DOM library because it's better integrated and more powerful (and actually works):

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla Firefox'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
$url = 'http://www.sony.co.za/product/dsc-wx10';
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url);
```